# Errors using extension CLI - 'Cannot use import statement outside a module'

Tags: javascript, npm, google-chrome-extension, importerror

I have been trying to import the node package Afinn-165 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/afinn-165) into my google chrome extension. The code currently scrapes the text of each page, and I would like to perform sentiment analysis on the text. I'm very new to web development so am learning as I go.

I have installed extension CLI through the following commands

```
npx extension-cli
npm install extension-cli
```

It works great until I put the following into background.js

```
import {afinn165} from 'afinn-165';
```

After which I get a 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' error

From what I've read online, the afinn-165 package should be importable and usable but instead the whole extension isn't working. I have looked at other implementations of extension CLI and they have used

```
import { package } from "package";
```

successfully, so I'm unsure of what to do now.

Comment: You need to build your extension as shown in the documentation for cli e.g. `npm run watch`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"type": "module"` to your package.json file.

Comment: I've added it to both package.json files (one is at top-level and another in node_modules) and the error is still there